# Likelihood-function : How to simplify it?

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

The fracture strength of hard bricks satisfies an Erlang distribution of order $2$. There are $n \in \mathbb{N}$ fracture strength tests that are carried out.

We consider the statistical product model $(X ,(P_{\theta})_{\theta \in \Theta})$ with $X = (0,\infty)^n$, $\Theta = (0,\infty)$ and densities $f_{\theta}(x_i) = \theta^2x_ie^{-\theta x_i}$
for all $x_i \in (0,\infty)$, $\theta \in \Theta$.

I want to calculate the Likelihood-function.

I have done the following :

\begin{equation*}L_x(\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^nf_{\theta}(x_i)=\prod_{i=1}^n \theta^2x_ie^{-\theta x_i}=\theta^{2n}e^{-\theta \sum_{i=1}^n x_i} \prod_{i=1}^nx_i\end{equation*} Is that correct so far?  How could we continue?

Comment: that looks correct - i don't think you can simplify much further.. usually you compute the log-likelihood which makes it easier to find $\theta^*$ that maximizes the likelihood

Comment: Ok, great! Thank you !! :-) @WeakLearner